# Asp.net Gridview: when add row there is no data from textboxes in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, textbox

this is my first question so if you don't understand it say it so i will be more specific.

This is my aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 0px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nummer" HeaderText="Nummer" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Omschrijving" ControlStyle-Width="300px">
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_omschrijvingbank" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grootboekrekening">
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dr_grootboek" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="grootboekrekening" DataValueField="grootboekrekeningnummer"></asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Btw">
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_btw" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Selecteer btw</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>21%</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6%</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>0%</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Debet">
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_debet" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Credet">
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_credit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_voegtoe" OnClick="Button3_Click" runat="server" Text="Voeg toe" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

en this is my code behind

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            gridVIEWData();
            begin();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }
    private void gridVIEWData()
    {
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nummer", typeof(string)));
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Omschrijving", typeof(string)));
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Grootboekrekening", typeof(string)));
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Btw", typeof(string)));
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Debet", typeof(string)));
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Credit", typeof(string)));

        Session["dtInSession"] = dt1;     //Saving Datatable To Session 
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["dtInSession"] != null)
            dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dtInSession"]; //Getting datatable from session 

        TextBox Omschrijving = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_omschrijvingbank");
        DropDownList Grootboekrekening = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("drp_grootboek");
        DropDownList Btw = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("drp_btw");
        TextBox Debet = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_debet");
        TextBox Credit = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_credit");

        Response.Write(Credit.Text);

        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Nummer"] = 1;
        dr["Omschrijving"] = Omschrijving.Text;
        dr["Grootboekrekening"] = Grootboekrekening.SelectedItem;
        dr["Btw"] = Btw.SelectedItem;
        dr["Debet"] = Debet.Text;
        dr["Credit"] = Credit.Text;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

        Session["dtInSession"] = dt1;     //Saving Datatable To Session 
        GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    private void begin()
    {
        if (Session["dtInSession"] != null)
            dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dtInSession"]; //Getting datatable from session 
        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Nummer"] = 1;
        dr["Omschrijving"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Grootboekrekening"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Btw"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Debet"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Credit"] = string.Empty;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["dtInSession"] = dt1;     //Saving Datatable To Session 
        GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

in the footer there are a couple texboxes and a button, if you push the button it will create a new row with the data that you have write in the textbox. but here is the problem: it is creating a new row!! But there is no data in the row.

i hope some of you can help me. if you need more detail please ask

Daan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to successfully update the data in the database, and the only problem is that it is not showing the data after update then you just need to reload the page.
Try:
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

Comment: the problem is that i do not want the data immediately in database first the user must add a couple rows with data and aftes he is finished it will be stored in a database. and the problem is now that there is no data in the rows. so i cant store anything in the database